# how to prevent joomla from loading google analytics script (ga.js)

Tags: google-analytics, joomla

For some unknown reason Joomla loads ga.js from google servers by default. The call is located in the file libraries/joomla/google/embed/analytics.php

How can I prevent loading of the script without modifying the core files?

Comment: Firstly check template which you are using are not enabling the google analytics, If your template does not have any setting then check any plugin which doing same thing.

Comment: @raVan96 It is beeing loaded on a fresh joomla 3.8.7 installation with both the beez and protostar templates with no 3rd party addons

Comment: There will be something that is Loading or enabling the code of google analytics. Joomla default doesn't add any analytics code. Did you face this issue on production environment or local environment ?

Comment: Can you check the index.php file of both template ? Might be the head tag have <script> tag which is loading this ga.js file

Comment: Definitely not coming from the template. It's being loaded with the  <jdoc:include type ="head" />. It is added through the library mentioned above in my original post even on a clean installation. The result is a script tag with the src ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js  see Screenshot: http://imagebucket.net/rrdt443uosun/joomla_ga.PNG

Comment: That's strange, I have installed same joomla on my local machine and it doesn't add this script tag at all. I am really sorry but are you 100% sure you don't have 3rd party extension on site ?

Comment: @raVan96 hi man, thanks a lot for looking into it. i have finally found the culprit: it was a browser extension called "Contrast Ratio Checker" that injected the code.

Comment: Owhoooo.... cheers man glad that your problem got solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joomla does not add google analytics code at all on fresh installation.

So You need to check below stuff and make sure it is not a browser extension :)

1. Firstly check template which you are using are not enabling the google analytics. Most of Joomla template does have google analytics option.
2. If above case is not true then , You need to check the index.php file of template ? Might be someone have added script tag there it self in head section.
3. If above both two case are failed then it might have chance of any system plugin triggering off which loads that google analytics code. So you need to disable that plguin by going to Administrator->Extensions->Plugins. Add filter of system plugin and disabled it.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the confusion: it turns out, it wasn't Joomla after all, but a Browser extension that loaded the script.

In my case it was Contrast Ratio Checker for Chrome.